# Which to Prefer IN vs Join vs Equals in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I want to get the Manufacturer from tbl_Manufacturer. I wrote three different Queries to get Manufacturers of the Item from tbl_Sales_OrderItems table. I Want to know which one to prefer. Will someone let me know which query should be used over other and why?

**Query 1: Using Subquery**

```
SELECT manufacturer
FROM   tbl_Manufacturers
WHERE  ManufacturerID IN(SELECT trc.ManufacturerID
                         FROM   tbl_Sales_RepairCategory trc
                         WHERE  trc.RepairCategoryID IN (SELECT RepairCategoryID
                                                         FROM   tbl_VendorParts
                                                         WHERE  VendorPartID IN (SELECT refid
                                                                                 FROM   tbl_Sales_OrderItems
                                                                                 WHERE  typeid = 2
                                                                                        AND SalesOrderID = 182)))
```

**Query 2: Using Sub-Query with Distinct**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Manufacturer
FROM   tbl_Manufacturers m,
       tbl_VendorParts tvp,
       tbl_Sales_RepairCategory trc
WHERE  tvp.RepairCategoryID = trc.RepairCategoryID
       AND trc.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID
       AND tvp.VendorPartID IN (SELECT Refid
                                FROM   tbl_Sales_OrderItems
                                WHERE  isnull(typeid, 0) = 2
                                       AND SalesOrderID = 182)
```

**Query 3: Using '=' (equals) with Distinct, join**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Manufacturer
FROM   tbl_Manufacturers m,
       tbl_VendorParts tvp,
       tbl_Sales_RepairCategory trc
WHERE  tvp.RepairCategoryID = trc.RepairCategoryID
       AND trc.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID
       AND tvp.VendorPartID = (SELECT Refid
                               FROM   tbl_Sales_OrderItems
                               WHERE  isnull(typeid, 0) = 2
                                      AND SalesOrderID = 182)
```

here is the **Execuition plan**:
[image]

Please suggest which to use?

Suggestions Appreciated!

Comment: `=` may cause a query to fail. So I wouldn't use it at all, regardless performance.

Comment: Usually, prefer the form that most clearly (to you) conveys what result you're trying to achieve - how *you* think about the problem and any sub-problems. Only if, after having done so, and the query isn't performing adequately, consider re-writing the parts that are performing badly.

Comment: Interesting. The query plan shows 3rd is the fast one as the cost is only 24%, lower than the other two. However, `=` may fail if you have multiple `Refid` records in the sub query.

Comment: "Query 1: Using JOIN" doesn't contain a `JOIN`?

Comment: I would suggest creating index first. Could you try to add some indices and try it again? `CREATE INDEX ix_VendorParts_RepairCategoryID ON tbl_VendorParts(RepairCategoryID)
CREATE INDEX ix_Sales_RepairCategory_RepairCategoryID ON tbl_Sales_RepairCategory(RepairCategoryID)
CREATE INDEX ix_Manufacturers_ManufacturerID on tbl_Manufacturers(ManufacturerID)
CREATE INDEX ix_Sales_OrderItems_SalesOrderID on tbl_Sales_OrderItems(SalesOrderID)`

Comment: All of the queries look pretty horrible to be honest. Use `ANSI-92` join syntax. Also `WHERE  isnull(typeid, 0) = 2` should be avoided and just replaced with `WHERE typeid = 2`. As that is sargable and it doesn't change the semantics.

Comment: As @zhongxiao37 says they don't have the same semantics anyway though. That assert operator in the final plan enforces an asssumption not present in the other queries for example.

Comment: so guys what would be the conclusion "Query 1" or "Query 2" ?

Comment: Neither for me. I'd favour the approach of using `IN` or `EXISTS` rather than bringing back duplicates and getting rid of them with `DISTINCT` but I'd probably avoid that level of nesting and have everything under that semi join just written as a join.

Comment: Don't just look at the "cost" or percent in an execution plan. Check the statistics IO and Time. Also try a couple of different permutation of input to allow for execution plan caching to take effect. Then you're in a better position to judge. Personally - I'd try a normal join structure through the entire query to avoid the subqueries. The large cost of sorts indicates you may benefit from specialized indexes.

Answer (score 1):

- In *general*, `IN` == poor performance.
- In *general*, joins are the way to go.
- Pre-SQL92 (old fashioned) joins that have the join condition in the where clause should be coded using the "new" (20+ years old) `join` syntax

None of your proposed queries would perform as well as this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Manufacturer
FROM tbl_Sales_OrderItems s
JOIN tbl_VendorParts tvp ON tvp.VendorPartID = s.Refid
JOIN tbl_Sales_RepairCategory trc ON tvp.RepairCategoryID = trc.RepairCategoryID
JOIN tbl_Manufacturers m ON trc.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID
WHERE (typeid = 2 OR typeid IS NULL)
AND SalesOrderID = 182
```

Notes:

- all joins have been converted to proper joins
- the table join order has been *reversed*, so the where clause operates on the first table listed, so indexes can be most effectively used and importantly as few row access operations as possible are needed
- typeid condition has been converted to an OR to avoid the isnull() function being called

Comment: +1 though I wish you would indent the less-important keywords from the main keywords (JOIN, AND, etc.). Your query is so hard to scan with that formatting.

Comment: So @ErikE which query will you prefer over other. will you please let me know if some other query u have in mind then please post it here..

Answer (score 0):

I like to use exists in this scenario. You know that you need to check the information in specific table columns, but you do not need to return any information from those tables. This is exactly what an exists is designed for. Exists tends to be more optimal than extra joins. The other nice thing about using exists is you are keeping the code cleaner. It is much easier to see what table you are pulling the necessary information from and that allows for easier maintainability in the future. I would recommend using something like this:

```
SELECT manufacturer
FROM   tbl_Manufacturers m
WHERE  exists   (SELECT 1
                FROM    tbl_Sales_RepairCategory trc
                join    tbl_VendorParts r
                On      trc.RepairCategoryID = r.RepairCategoryID
                join    tbl_Sales_OrderItems s
                On      s.refid = r.VendorPartID
                Where   m.ManufacturerID  = trc.ManufacturerID
                and     r.typeid = 2
                and     r.salesOrderId = 182)
```

Comment: +1 on the `EXISTS` but -1 for suggesting `SELECT TOP 1 1`. You don't need `TOP` in an `EXISTS` query, and furthermore, best practice is simply `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ...)`. (So no vote up or down.) Also, I can't stand formatting that places main keywords like `SELECT` and `FROM` at the same level as `JOIN`, `ON`, and `AND`... do you really see that as helpful to other people trying to understand your query?

Comment: @Jenn will you please explain "payrCategoryID" which table you are refereing?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE sorry, typo.

Comment: @ErikE I agree on the top 1, but I disagree on the select *. It is possible that I have not seen the documentation supporting that, but a select should never have more columns than necessary. In theory you could force sql server into a key lookup. Also, the formatting is a matter of preference and I thought this format would be helpful in this case because it emphasizes the keywords namely the exists. This code should not be copied and pasted, but rather evaluated based on the idea. The OP will need to do their own optimization and make changes based on the needs of their client.

Comment: Oracle had to modify their engine to make `SELECT 1` work properly in an `EXISTS` clause--people were ignorantly spreading old wives' tales about how it was better than the syntax called for by the standard, `SELECT *`. I promise you, DBMS makers are not stupid, and there is no performance benefit to using any other syntax. Combined with the `TOP`, your query strongly communicated inexperience. Just use what the standard calls for and be consistent!

Comment: Again, documentation? There isn't much out there that comments on this and if I am going to use it, I would like to read about it. I would disagree with "just use what the standard calls for" on the basis that it is not our job to regurgitate, but rather to understand. It is unfortunate that you view my query as communicating inexperience as opposed to communicating learning - as they say, the best way to learn is to teach. Lastly, I am consistent; I have consistently used 'select 1'. My habits and understandings may evolve and that is part of the process. No one was born a sql master.

Comment: @Jenn I am sorry I came across a bit strongly, there. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx. You're right that resources on this topic are hard to find. I read a blog post in the past my a Microsoft insider who said that * is no worse performance and is the standard. I'll try to find more resources. Also, try `EXISTS (SELECT 1/0 ...)` which should prove at least partially to you what I'm saying. P.S. If you don't tag someone, he won't be notified of your response.

Comment: @ErikE Thank you. Everything that I found online essentially stated that these are essentially equivalent and that this is a discussion dating back years. I did try your suggestion (Select 1/0) and the results were almost identical. It seems that this is more a matter of personal preference.
http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2009/09/age-old-select-vs-select-1-debate.html

Comment: @Jenn It wasn't the `SELECT 1` by itself, but the `SELECT TOP 1 1` that prompted my initial comments, suggesting that the writer of the query didn't understand what `EXISTS` does.